# Why did Marco Polo say the Buddhist religion originated in Sielan?

Tags: history, buddha

[image]

Read page 295 [here](https://archive.org/details/travelsmarcopol00murrgoog/page/n295).

Also refer to the editorial note on p.289 “*this is the well known island of Ceylon, both direction and distance are extremely correct*”.

**A Summary.**

Until 1890 the world knew Buddha was from Sri Lanka. In addition to Marco Polo, Pre-1890 historical references from Robert Knox, a Bible commentary and Sir, Henry Charles are provided.  More here -> https://jambudipa.quora.com

How the history was allegedly distorted is mentioned [here](https://jambudipa.quora.com). Does this sound credible?

Comment: The OP is a Sinhalese, my bet. I read the front and back total 3 pages from his link, it doesn't say as the OP hoped: *"Why did Marco Polo say the Buddhist religion born in Sielan?"* Marco Polo only described he encountered the islanders (Sielan residents) worshiping an "Adam" (the Buddha image). It's an **old task** in the internet arena many Sinhalese trying every means to promote the Buddha and Buddhism born in Ceylon. Good luck for your clause here! Hope the world do hear and accept your countrymen's claim, bravo!!!!

Comment: "Origin of Boodhist Religion in Seilan" is in the title. I think you missed it.  I have added a new link with other references including from a Bible commentary.

Comment: I don't understand the question. According to [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Travels_of_Marco_Polo#/media/File:Travels_of_Marco_Polo.svg) he travelled via Ceylon i.e. he visited there. And the page you quoted says, "**They describe this** last as the first man [etc.] son to a king [etc.]" So is the answer is because, he says, that's what "they" (i.e. the "idolaters" i.e. statue-worshippers) on Ceylon described to him. He's saying that because, according to him, that's what he was told. Does that answer your question, what else is there to ask about that?

Comment: The First Tipitaka was written in Sri Lanka in Sinhala letters. Buddha's hair, bones, tooth relic, and his robe all exist in Sri Lanka. Names like Ananda, Kosala and Anurudha are all Sinhala names even still in use. Sinhala is derived from Maghadhi and a large number of words are common still.  Nepal did not receive Buddhism till 6 CE. (Read the link above).  So add these together with commentary by Marco Polo and see where that takes you,

Comment: The further reasons you give in the comment aren't relevant to explaining the question i.e. "Why did Marco Polo say...?" Instead, that most-recent comment would only be relevant to answering a different question i.e., "Why do I believe that ...?" or "Why do I teach that ...?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is meant for question-and-answer, i.e. for asking questions -- and not for pushing (preaching) views or doctrines, and not for holding (initiating) arguments or discussions -- and what's posted as a "question" doesn't seem to be an actual question, it can only be intended and understood as part of a longer argument being pushed.

Comment: Yes so people of Sri Lanka 800 years ago tells Marco Polo Buddha lived there and he is the best ever lived in the island etc.  He visits India, China and many other countries too. No one told him anything contradictory when he visited those countries. So the answer to the question is Buddha living in the island was the world opinion at that time.

Comment: Its about Buddha and history. Not "off-topic".

Comment: Also, the "why they did this"-type questions are hard to answer objectively. Who knows why, and how can we know? We can only speculate, while this site is about knowledge sharing.

Comment: I asked on Meta -- [Should this question (about the historical Buddha living in Sri Lanka) be reopened?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2318/254)

Comment: @Mishu米殊 that was harsh tone in your comment, please avoid.

Comment: Well, if the history I have presented here is right, everything you know about Buddhism is wrong. So instead of petty rules I would focus on what is in the best interest of the Buddhist community.  Do you want to learn the truth or continue pursing something that never works. The ball is in your court.

Comment: OP: *"The First Tipitaka was written in Sri Lanka in **Sinhala letters**."* It conformed to my insight after reading Wikipedia on Pali Canon stating the Pali commentaries were written in Sinhalese until Buddhaghosa translated to "Pali" and burnt the original texts - suspicious. With access to Chinese historical documents and texts, the truth is too prominent to hide; but the rest of the world still don't know. You shouldn't reveal what was the original favour of the Pali Canon if you wish to raise the importance of Sri Lanka in Buddhism, my thoughtful advice, @user2615131

Comment: This is not a nationalistic thing trying to promote Sri Lanka etc. Say you found a book on the floor gathering dust and dirt. You pick it up and leave it on the table isnt' it? Its like that. The history is wrong. The attempt here is to correct the history for everyone's benefit.

Comment: I think this is a great question to ask on [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) but not suitable here. I propose to migrate this question to History.SE.

Comment: @ruben2020 I don't think I should migrate it. The OP could post it as a new question on History.SE (I don't know what the guidelines for posting there are).

Answer (score 2):

Probably because he was told so and never started to investigate the real origin of things? Even today there are many Sinhalese people claiming the origin in the country they live. One may find such similar thoughts in all other countries and one also may find Jesus with balck skin or Chinese eyes in other countries. That's the nature and requirement for all -isms and -ists: Strong Self-identification.

Dhamma and means for liberation should not be dig up be focus on objectification ([pacanca](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/papanca_en.html)) although it is usually refined identification what gives one rise toward interest and can be used of course also strategical wise "What, if I let go of it, would lead to my long term happiness?", thought of "who ever defines one self, limits and suffers with it", especially if not something leading to go beyond.

If Marco Polo ever had met the good Dhamma, real "Buddists", he would not have returned. So it's probably good to investigate travelers who found the way that leads to rest.

> “Is it possible, lord, by traveling, to know or see or reach a far end of the cosmos where one does not take birth, age, die, pass away or reappear?”
>
> “I tell you, friend, that it is not possible by traveling to know or see or reach a far end of the cosmos where one does not take birth, age, die, pass away, or reappear.” ...
>   But at the same time, I tell you that there is no making an end of suffering & stress without reaching the end of the cosmos. Yet it is just within this fathom-long body, with its perception & intellect, that I declare that there is the cosmos, the origination of the cosmos, the cessation of the cosmos, and the path of practice leading to the cessation of the cosmos.” [Rohitassa Sutta](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/tipitaka/sut/sn/sn02/sn02.026.than)

*{Note that this has not been given to keep one on wandering on by trade, exchange, stacks, or use it for such, but for liberation}*

To answer a further argument, actually not leading to liberation at all:

"Well, Marco Polo visited India and China along the way too. If he found Buddha existed in India then he would have mentioned it that way instead."

Why should he have traveled around and possible ask everywhere the same question, everybody he meets? If one lives amoung people with a certain believe, then one might be missinformed, since not knowing. As the Dhamma is about seeing your self (to gain liberation), what is not possible of thing which have already decayed (history), it does not support the feed the attention on improper means but to come there where reality happens and why. Once again in other words:

> “Is it possible, lord, by researching, to know or see or reach the Buddha or Dhamma, where one does not take birth, age, die, pass away or reappear?”
>
> “I tell you, friend, that it is not possible by research to know or see or reach the Buddha or the Dhamma where one does not take birth, age, die, pass away, or reappear.” ...
>   But at the same time, I tell you that there is no making an end of suffering & stress without researching after the Buddha and the Dhamma. **Yet it is just within this fathom-long body, with its perception & intellect, that I declare that there is The Buddha and the Dhamma, the the origination of The Buddha and the Dhamma, the cessation of the Buddha and the Dhamma, and the path of practice leading to the cessation of The Buddha and the Dhamma**.”

In regard of places, as the Buddha told, there is no place to be found in the world which is not actually a cementery, and ther is not a singe moment in the world in which no aging, sickness and death takes place. So what does one cling on here? Be wise. Don't waste your time, what ever might have been does not matter on the fact, that a raw possibility to be born as human, possible not stupid (?) and meeting the Dhamma, might be wasted away!

Comment: Well, Marco Polo visited India and China along the way too. If he found Buddha existed in India then he would have mentioned it that way instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably at that time period, Buddhism were established in Ceylon at early stage, just because that we can not tell that it is true. Even the places which mentioned in Dharma, can not find here in Ceylon, like Mount Himalaya, Gijjakuta Rock.